# Handle Neo4j Injection for dynamic labels and relationships

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, neo4j, neo4jclient, neo4j-apoc

I have been usingWithParams with neo4j client for c# but withParams don't work for label or relationship types for example.

The alternative I thought of the moment was to concatenate my string that I want to form based on some label as parameter and then construct the cypher query. That is:

```
string optionalMatchString = $"p =(n1)-[{relationshipsString}]-(n2)";
graphClient.Cypher.Match("(n1)")
           .Where((Node n1) => n1.Identifier == identifier)
           .OptionalMatch(optionalMatchString)
```

As you can guess, relationshipsString is a parameter passed to me. If I use WithParams the query will not substitute the parameters so for now I concatenate the string but this is vulnearble to attacks ... (yes?)

I learned about [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and saw [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/544)

This is an example I saw [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/177):

```
CALL db.labels() yield label
call apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n:`"+label+"`) RETURN keys(n) as keys LIMIT 1",{}) yield value as row
RETURN label, row.keys as keys
```

Apparently, there is an APOC procedure called `cypher.run` in which I can put my labels (or relationships for that matter) as variables (from the parameters) but from what I see, they are just concatenating a string... so is that the same as what I have been doing? or does APOC somehow perform other stuff on top of the query? Would that APOC procedure be "safe" against injections?

Comment: Do you have a predefined set of relationships in your database? If you do, you can just whitelist the relationship type, i.e. check if it is a member of the possible relationship type. If it isn't, just reject the request.

Comment: I have that as backup but I don’t want to go around that route. There must be a wat to avoid neo4j injection with this...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a predefined set of relationships in your database, you can just whitelist the relationship type, i.e. check if it is a member of the possible relationship type.

If that does not work you for some reason, you can still pass the label as a parameter and use the [`labels`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-labels) method in Cypher. However, this will be detrimental to the performance, as the database will query all nodes and check their types with a filtering operation.

I know this is a C# question, but let me share some Java code to reproduce this:

```
GraphDatabaseService gds = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory()
    .newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder().newGraphDatabase();
ApocHelper.registerProcedure(gds, Cypher.class);
gds.execute("CREATE (:MyLabel {attr1: 'hello'})");
Result result = gds.execute(
    "CALL apoc.cypher.run(" +
        "'MATCH (n) WHERE $label1 IN labels(n) RETURN keys(n) as keys LIMIT 1', " +
        "{label1: $label2}" +
    ") " +
    "YIELD value AS row " +
    "RETURN row",
    ImmutableMap.of("label2", "MyLabel")
);
System.out.println(result.next());
```

This returns:

```
{row={keys=[attr1]}}
```

But again, this is an academic solution and I cannot really think of a use case where this would be the best.

(In parallel to this question, there is a discussion in an [APOC issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/177) as well.)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

There is the risk of the db being wiped (see the comments below from @Gabor) but I would still go down the route of an Enum to solve this. However, Gabor's answer is better from that pov.

---

APOC is doing the same thing you are doing, so you won't get any benefits from using it. I think the key thing here is to look at the level of protection you need.

Taking your query, (I've made a guess at the `RETURN` bit) which boils down to:

`MATCH (n) WHERE n.Id = {p0} OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:{injectionPoint}]->(n1) RETURN n, n1`

Let's look at what we could get from this, assuming the attacker knows the following information:

- The format you are returning (i.e. the info you get from `n` and `n1`)
- How your query is structured, i.e. know that you are returning a node called `n1`

They could try adding another query, i.e. injecting something like:

`"ORIGINAL]->(n1) RETURN n1; MATCH (n) RETURN labels(n);"`

But that won't work for two reasons, one the `Cypher` endpoint you're calling will only accept one query at a time, and two, the response from `MATCH (n) RETURN labels(n)` won't match the response you're currently getting and so will error.

The biggest risk you have is with someone being able work out your model by passing in different relationship types until they get responses - this would take ages though, so probably not such an issue.

The attacker does *have* to know the info above to get this out though, without that, they'll just be stabbing in the dark. And if they *do* have that info - then they probably already know what they could get from your DB.

If you took what you're doing and put it into a SQL context, you'd be asking for something from *any* table, with an ID, and then by providing a table name, looking for anything that connects to. Would you do that in SQL? Also - with no labels, you are scanning the *entire* database for this info, that's going to be super slow.

I think you'd do well to add labels, at *least* to one of the nodes, if not both, and use something like an Enum to represent your allowed relationships - I appreciate that's impractical for large numbers.

Comment: What happens if the attacker just wants to wipe your database? Take this string for example: `ORIGINAL]->(n1) WITH count(*) AS dummy MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE (n);`

Comment: That string wouldn't work for the same reason above - you'd have to try to execute 2 cypher queries in one go...

Comment: No, that will be a single Cypher query. `WITH count(*) AS dummy` always returns exactly one row, so you can effectively chain two queries into a single one.

Comment: Yup, you're right, the cypher you put wouldn't work due to the way the `C#` works in this case, but you can get that result. That is indeed an injection risk - my bad!